# 2 view controllers in one (collection view?)

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have this problem: I need to open a PDF document and display several of my elements at the bottom of the display (button, text field). Pdf documents open as any view controller:

```
let document = PDFDocument(url: remotePDFDocumentURL)!
let readerController = PDFViewController.createNew(with: document)
navigationController?.pushViewController(readerController, animated: true)
```

The first thing that occurred to me was to use collection view. But it has not turned out yet, because the PDF document is created dynamically. And honestly I did not use CV before.
Probably there is a less correct way - just add the elements to the created (PDF) view controller, and move all the elements a little higher.

Prompt the right decision, Thank you!

Comment: Use Container view (i.e add readerController.view as a sub view of your main view controller's view and add readerController as a child of main VC).

Comment: I still din get why collectionView ? What is it you are trying to do ? You have a button and a text field on top and when you tap a button u wanna open and show pdf below it thats all? If yes add PDFViewController as a subview to your view shouldn't that do ur job ?

Comment: Add content of your two views on one viewController in which you are displaying fullView Pdf and if you want to show two views one time add a container view which will be having view of your second collectionView

Comment: Thanks men! It really was solved by adding the controller as a child. I set the size for the view and placed below all the necessary components for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following (Just in pseudo-code, because I don't have Xcode available at the moment):

- Create your own view controller, let's call it `ContainerViewController`
- Add your custom controls into it
- Add a placeholder view (with outlet) for the PDF into it
- Layout everything as you like
- Add the *view* of the `PDFViewController` as a subview into the container; lay it out
- (if needed: make the `PDFViewController` accessible from your container)
- Fulfill the [view container containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) requirements in your container view controller
- Push your container onto the navigation controller